# Ho do I access the examples mentioned in the Apache Camel documentation

Tags: apache-camel

The Apache camel documentation has examples given like {snippet:id=e2|lang=java|url=camel/trunk/components/camel-sql/...

Example - The link http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html has these in the Sample section.

How do I access these samples?

Comment: Go to https://github.com/apache/camel/ and search for the related class mentioned in the sample section e.g https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/3505e718db48cc0d8be5b47f6c4030c958d93a5f/components/camel-sql/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/sql/SqlDataSourceRefTest.java

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looking under the examples, didn't think of checking under the components test folders.

Comment: You can/should browse the examples at: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples#examples - those are the up-to-date examples. The website is undergoing a new layout and documentation which will not be ready before 2018.